# Isometric projection : What's wrong with my math?

Tags: math, matrix, isometric

I have an math problem in Isometric projection. I have reading an article: [Axonometric projections - a technical overview](http://www.compuphase.com/axometr.htm#CARTESIO).  For the Isometric projection part, it give an mathematical formula for conversion 3D point into 2D point for the x part the formula is:

```
x' = ( x − z ) cos(30);
```

But i also check for wiki for [Isometric Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) so i use the rotation matrices which the wiki giving, calculate myself

```
x' = x*cos(beta) - z*sin(beta)
```

The beta is define by the wiki(Y axis rotation angle, and it should be 45).  So what's wrong with my math?  Or is there something that i don't know about the Isometric projection?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your `cos` and `sin` take degrees and not radians?

```
// C/C++ code

#define PI 3.141592654
static const float PI_RADIANS = PI / 180.f;

inline float DegToRad(float a_Degrees)
{
   return (a_Degrees * PI_RADIANS);
}

inline float RadToDeg(float a_Radians)
{
   return (a_Radians / PI_RADIANS);
}
```